# jquery with checkbox and anchor tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery

if I have a checkbox next to an anchor tag, how do I use jQuery to display an alert box with the anchor tags href value when the checkbox is clicked.

For example,

```
<div><input type="checkbox"><a href="http://link0">link 0</a></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><a href="http://link1">link 1</a></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><a href="http://link2">link 2</a></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><a href="http://link3">link 3</a></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><a href="http://link4">link 4</a></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><a href="http://link5">link 5</a></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><a href="http://link6">link 6</a></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><a href="http://link7">link 7</a></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><a href="http://link8">link 8</a></div>
<div><input type="checkbox"><a href="http://link9">link 9</a></div>
```

if i click on the checkbox next oto link 7, it should alert me with

```
http://link7
```

and so on.

Comment: An unrelated suggestion: the `<input>` element should be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() { 
    alert($(this).nextAll('a:first').attr('href'));
});
```

**EDIT**: Explanation:

- The [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selects all checkboxes.
- `$(this).nextAll('a:first')` will find the first `<a>` element after `this`, even if there are other elements in between.
  By contrast, `$(this).next('a') will only return the next element if it's an``; if there is something in between, it won't return anything.

Comment: why is this better than using Vincent Ramdhanie suggestion?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing 'nextAll('a:first')'? Can't you just do 'next('a')'?

Comment: @oshirowanen - Because you don't HAVE to use a class to select the checkboxes (whereas Vincent's answer does require that). However, there are reasons why you may want to use Vincent's answer (see my comment on his response).

Comment: `:checkbox` as a bare selector passed to jQuery is inefficient.  Use `input:checkbox` - http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Answer (score 3):

You've already gotten alot of good answers, but here's how I would do it:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    alert($(this).next()[0].href);
});
```

Using the `:checkbox` selector alone is the same as doing `*:checkbox` which is the same as `*:[type="checkbox"]`, and you don't want to check the type attribute of all the elements in the DOM.

Also, since jQuery is all about *write less, do more*, I advice using the native method as often as possible to get attributes, it means less code and is a tiny bit faster (but that's really negible).

Use `.next()[0]` if the anchor element is the immediate sibling of the checkbox. Otherwise you use `.nextAll("a:first")[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Start by adding a class to the checkboxes like this:

```
<input class="chkbox" type="checkbox"/>
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
  $(".chkbox").click(function(){
       alert($(this).next("a").attr("href"));
  });
```

Comment: @oshirowanen - You don't necessarily need to add a class for this to work (see SLaks answer). However, it would help if you have other checkboxes on the page that you DO NOT to want to have this functionality.

Comment: why is this better than using SLaks suggestion?

Comment: @oshirowanen Both answers are very similar and I don't think one is better than the other. This sometimes happens when two persons with the same idea are typing at the same time.

Comment: This won't work if there is an element between the checkbox and the link.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
  $('checkbox').click(function() {
   var ref =$(this).next().attr('href')
   alert(ref);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if( $(this).attr('checked') ){
            window.location = '#' + $(this).next('a').attr('href');
        }
    });

});
```